# How to get request object from response (node-fetch)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I want to get `request Object` from `response` using node-fetch lib. For example my request failed:

```js
const ok = await response.ok
console.log(ok) // ->false
```

And I want to get request info from my response to repeat it. It will be good something like this:

```js
const request_headers = await response.request.headers
const request_url = await response.request.url
const request_body = await response.request.body
const request_agent = await response.request.agent
```

Is there a way to do it with node-fetch?

Comment: I am still confused. What do you mean by `Request Object`?

Comment: @BadPiggie I mean get the request from response